# PHP Listing dates as month ABBR

Tags: php

I had a hiccup in my code somewhere and got the syntax wrong so my dates don't work for
some reason or another. I pretty sure its a syntax flaw with strtotime. I don't think its
using my integer like I thought it would. Could someone take a look and tell me how to fix
this?

```
    <td> 
        <select name="bday[month]" id="bday[month]">
            <?php foreach( range(1,12) as $month) { echo "<option value='$month'>".date('M', strtotime($month))."</option>\r\t\t\t"; } ?>
        </select>

        <select name="bday[day]" id="bday[day]">
            <?php foreach( range(1,31) as $day) { echo "<option value='$day'>$day</option>\r\t\t\t"; } ?>
        </select>

        <select name="bday[year]" id="bday[year]">
            <?php foreach( range(date('Y')-13, 1900) as $year) { echo "<option value='$year'>$year</option>\r\t\t\t"; } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime()` needs more than just the month digit.

I'd suggest using [`mktime()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) instead.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; ++$i) {
    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i)) . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you're passing strtotime an integer argument. You should be passing a string. :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score -1):

```
<td> 
    <select name="bday[month]" id="bday[month]">
        <?php foreach( range(1,12) as $month) { echo "<option value='$month'>".sprintf("%02d", $month)."</option>\r\t\t\t"; } ?>
    </select>

    <select name="bday[day]" id="bday[day]">
        <?php foreach( range(1,31) as $day) { echo "<option value='$day'>$day</option>\r\t\t\t"; } ?>
    </select>

    <select name="bday[year]" id="bday[year]">
        <?php foreach( range(date('Y')-13, 1900) as $year) { echo "<option value='$year'>$year</option>\r\t\t\t"; } ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: I need feedback, not a '-1' only.